# How to change the Hive Field data type in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile-application

```
@HiveField()
late List<String> images;
```

Currently, I have assigned List  for images
but I want to change it into XFile as :

```
List<XFile>.
```

I have already assigned some data to :

```
List<String> images;
```

Do my images data will appear as before or data will be lost ?

I haven't tried anything and I want to know before implementing.
And also afraid of losing the images data which is already stored in hive database.Want to see some sample any and if anyone has done it before.

Answer (score 0):

It won't work as both fields have different types and changing type for the same HiveField is not supported as stated [here](https://docs.hivedb.dev/#/custom-objects/generate_adapter?id=updating-a-class). You should add a new HiveField for that.

Comment: Thanks! Able to solve by adding new hive fields.